# Fractions involving two variables

Tags: calculus

Let $0\leq x\leq 1, 0\leq y\leq 1.$ It is a straight forward fact that 
$$\frac{1-x}{1+x}\leq \frac{1-xy}{1+xy}.$$ But can we find an appropriate $f(x)$ such that 
$$f(x)\frac{1-x}{1+x}\geq \frac{1-xy}{1+xy}f(xy)?$$

Comment: The answer depends what properties of $f$ you are looking for. $f=0$ is an obvious example where the inequality holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple options. Start with the trivial $f(x)=0$. Another option for equality is $f(x)=\frac{1+x}{1-x}$. Both these yield equality. Starting from the second choice, multiply with any increasing function of $x$ to yield strict inequality. For example $$f(x)=x\frac{1+x}{1-x}$$

Answer (score 0):

Considering $f(x) =\frac{1-x}{1+x}$

we have

$$
0\le f(x) \le 1 \ \ \forall\  0\le x \le 1
$$

and is strictly decreasing because $f'(x) = -\frac{2}{(x+1)^2}$

now if $0 \le y \le 1\Rightarrow x y \le x \Rightarrow f(y x) \ge f(x)$